# Url of ImageField in django query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-models

I have a model `ModelA` with a field of type ImageField. Now, I want to get all the images' urls in one go.

So, when I do ModelA.objects.all().values(), I want to get something like:

```
[{"id":1, "image_field": "/media/upload_folder/xyz.jpg"}, {...}]
```

Now, it gives something like:

```
[{"id":1, "image_field": "upload_folder/xyz.jpg"}, {...}]
```

Am I missing something?

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MEDIA_URL can change, so Django doesn't store it in the database. You can prepend it yourself:

```
from django.conf import settings

values = ModelA.objects.all().values()
for value in values:
    value['image_field'] = settings.MEDIA_URL + value['image_field']
```

Comment: This gave me some idea Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't work if you store your images in S3 for example

Answer (score 1):

The MEDIA_URL in your settings.py file is variable, so it can't add it at the beginning for you.

Loop through each object and prepend the MEDIA_URL value yourself.

```
for value in values:
    newURL = settings.MEDIA_URL
    newURL += value['image_field']
    value['image_field'] = newURL
```

Take extra care with slashes .... you dont want to end up with  two together // ... it depends on whether you have one at the end of your MEDIA_URL or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way too by using `Concat`,`Value` and `F`

```py
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

values = ModelA.objects.all().annotate(img_url=Concat(
    Value(settings.MEDIA_URL), F("image_field")
))
```

Now the `img_url` will have your desired output.