# Django - Parent imageField url isnt showing on template

Tags: python, django

This is my model structure.

```
Institution
 - name
 - logo
 - ....

Course
 - Owner ( foriegnKey with Institution )
 - name
 - terms
 - .....
```

So now, am just calling data's like.

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).values('id','name','terms','owner__name', 'owner__logo')
```

And trying to display the owner__logo as `{{data.owner__logo.url}}`. But its not working, as the img src shows (unknown). But when this Institution logo thing works on some other view when i directly call it. but when i call via relationship its not working.

If i use `{{data.owner__logo}}` then it just passes the url without the full path. How to make this work, please help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Url of ImageField in django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162558/url-of-imagefield-in-django-query)

Comment: My problem is getting ImageField from parent using relation. IF i use imagefield directly its working perfectly ! But when i fetch that from parent then its not working @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0):

An approach that worked for me after I've experimented is...

```
# Use the FK object id (owner_id) since you're dealing with a FK.
courses = Course.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).values('id','name','terms','owner_id')
```

If you should print the `courses dictionary` you'll see the `fields` it contains for each course. In this case, you'll see the `FK` with the `id` listed for that `object`. Example:

```
{'id': 10, 'owner_id': 7, 'name': 'Random', 'terms': 'Anything', ...}
```

What I did from here since the `courses` `object` is a `dictionary`, I've added a new `key` with with the `value` being the logo `url`.

```
for course in courses:
     # First is to get the owner object with the course['owner_id']
     owner = Institution.objects.get(id=course['owner_id'])

     # From the owner object, you have access to the logo and it's URL
     # Creating a new key called 'logo_url' and assigning the owner logo URL to it
     course['logo_url'] = owner.logo.url  

# Add the courses dictionary to the context variable
context['courses'] = courses
```

Then within your template, you can access the `logo_url` for each `course`.

```
{% for course in courses %}
     <img src="{{ course.logo_url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

***OPTION #2: A MORE EFFICIENT WAY***

The next option here is to use a `template filter` to get the `Institution object`'s logo `url` in just one go while you loop over the items in the template.

In your `custom_tags.py` file:

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_logo_url(bypass, owner_id):
     # owner = Institution.objects.get(id=owner_id)
     # or
     owner = get_object_or_404(Institution, id=owner_id) # Recommended
    
     if owner:
          url = owner.logo.url
     else:
          url = ""

     return url
```

In your `template` and `for loop`.

```
{% load custom_tags %}  # Must do to be able to use the custom filter


{% for course in courses %}
     {% with logo_url=""|get_logo_url:course.owner_id %}
          <img src="{{ logo_url }}" />
     {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you're not familiar with `django` custom `tags` and `filters`, you can see the [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Actually why Imagefield is not working when using foreign key relationship ?

Comment: In this context, it's not working because the `.values` method only captures the field names with the associated values, not the `FK` object. Therefore, you can't refer to `owner_id` as an object, it's just a field name holding the `FK` `id`.